# Objective-C retain count on assigning object to new pointer

Tags: objective-c, pointers, memory-leaks, retaincount

*Disclaimer: I'm pretty new to Objective-C*

I'm in a command-line project
ARC is NOT enabled

I  have a class called MyClass

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
@end

@implementation MyClass
@end
```

and my main looks like

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MyClass *first = [MyClass new];
    MyClass *second = first;
    return 0;
}
```

Questions:

1. I know that ***first** has a retain count of 1. But I don't
   understand why ***second** has retain count = 1 as well? I haven't
   done new, retain, alloc, or copy on that object.
2. Since ***first** has retain count of 1, do I have to call release on
   that? As you can see in the code, I have to release on the object, but Performance Analyzer shows no Memory-leak. Why?
3. I noticed that both ***first** and ***second** has the same value of
   memory address. Then I suppose that ***first** retain count should
   increase to 2 on assigning. But it does not, why?
4. I noticed that when I retain ***first** and assign it to ***second**
   both of them have retain count of 2 (see below)

   ```
   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
       MyClass *first = [MyClass new];
       [first retain];
       MyClass *second = first;
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   So basically ***second** becomes a COPY of ***first** in that case
   when is it released?
5. What happens to the retain count of both pointers if I change the
   code to

   ```
   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
       MyClass *first = [MyClass new];
       MyClass *second = first;
       [first retain];
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   I mean will ***second** retain count increase as well?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Note that absolute retain counts are useless when reasoning about memory management.  Think in terms of deltas.  Www.whentouseretaincount.com has (snarky) details.

Comment: @bbum but they are still essential to understand when learning and debugging.

Comment: Yes, @justinmeiners, it is essential to understand that the absolute retain count is useless and why (including not being useful for debugging).  Because it is useless outside of contrived examples that never happen in real code.

Answer (score 3):

1. You are correct by calling `new` or `alloc` an object is created with a retain count of 1.
2. Assigning `second` to `first` does not modify the retain count. Second is simply a **pointer** to the same object as first. Retain count is a variable on the object so therefore all pointers to the same object will always show same retain count.
3. You must either assign using a class `@property` or manually call `-retain` on to increment the retain count. What you are doing now is called a weak pointer. The assignment of second to first does not modify the original objects retain count.
4. Yes, once again both pointers are pointing to the same object. Modifications to the object will be reflected in both pointers.
5. Both pointers are pointing to the same object so by calling [first retain] a single object will be modified and all pointers pointing to it will show an increase in retain count.

You need to think of `first` and `second` as pointers, not individual objects. There is only one object in this program and that is the one created at `-new`. By calling release or retain on either the first or second pointer you are only making changes to the single object pointed to by both.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do I have to call release on both first and second? Do I have a memory-leak here because Performance Analyzer shows no leak.

Comment: You only need to call 1 release for every retain. In both code examples you create the object RC=1 and then you retain it. RC=2. Here is a leak. You could either call release twice to get RC=0 or you could remove the retain so RC=1 and call release once to get RC=0. It does not matter in this case whether you call retain and release on the first or the second object, because they point to the same thing messages are synonymous.

Comment: Do not assume that +new and +alloc return an object with RC of 1;  they return objects with RC +1.  Always think of the retain counts in terms of deltas.